# What hapens if I omit the "-m state" in iptables rules?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

Does it automatically accept packets from all states?
On that note, what is the difference between:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

and

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

and what is recommended for everyday use?

Also, I have seen that some people use "-p tcp -m tcp" notation and some just put "-p tcp". Is it correct to put "-m tcp" right after specifying protocol?

It is my first time configuring iptables and I want to be conscious of everything I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have `-m <match>` in the iptables command, you specify that the command can use functions from that module to test/match against certain properties of a packet. `-m state` is perhaps the most common, but there are a *ton* of interesting matchers available in iptables, for doing things like rate-limiting, quotas, etc, and you can find an overview of what's available [here](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html), organized by matcher names.

You'll find descriptions for [-m tcp](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbCF) and [-m state](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbCC) in the same document, and the [-m conntrack](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbAO) section has a good description of what the state names mean. In short, `NEW,ESTABLISHED` means incoming connection requests, and incoming packets which are associated with traffic going both ways, i.e. an established connection. If you didn't specify any --state at all, iptables wouldn't discriminate between `NEW,ESTABLISHED` and the other states `INVALID,RELATED,UNTRACKED` and just allow all incoming packets to port 22.

For regular use, I like being precise about what I allow through, which is why I generally use `--state NEW,ESTABLISHED`, though it's not completely necessary in my opinion.

For the `-m tcp`, you can see from the linked documentation that it gives you additional TCP-related matchers like `--tcp-flags`. As fas as I know, you don't need it for `--source-port/--sport` or `--dest-port/--dport`, so in most cases it's redundant.